# Why doesn't jQuery work when imported locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

When I import jQuery into my HTML from a web address I can get my accordion to work but if it is imported from my computer it doesn't. I know I may be importing the wrong file and if so is there a way to know?

```
<head>
    <!--Is my javascript-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JSabout.js"></script>

    <!--Is what I'm importing-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

This doesn't work

```
<head>
    <!--Is my javascript-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JSabout.js"></script>

    <!--Is what I'm importing-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

But this does

I am also trying to use a theme (Dot Luv)

Comment: Does JSabout.js include the code to setup elements as accordion?

Comment: Explain more, `it doesn't work` is too broad...  Is it 404?

Comment: Well, is there a `jquery-ui` folder in same folder as your webpage, with the jQuery scripts inside of it? What does the network tab of your browser's debug tools say when it tries to access those files?

Comment: Open up your browser's developer tools and check the 'Network' tab to see what kind of error is being processed when you are attempting to load in the jQuery files.

Comment: Did you try debugging it in the browser and see if everything is loaded properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery UI depends on jQuery.

In the working example you import jQuery then you import jQuery UI.

In the non working example,  you import jQuery UI, then you import an non-minified version of jQuery UI (don't do that, stick to one version), **then** you import jQuery, by which time it is too late.

It has nothing to do with being local. You've changed the order of the scripts.

Comment: @TristanWarren You probably would have noticed this if you looked at your browser's JavaScript debug console. It would be confused the first time it tried to use the jQuery library and give you an error.

Comment: That does work although the styling is not the same and looks awefull. Am I just using the wrong jQuery UI?

Comment: @TristanWarren — In the example where you imported jQuery UI twice, you didn't import the jQuery UI stylesheet at all.